# missing type specifier - int assumed C4430 error

Tags: c++, struct, header

**Situation:** I am attempting to create a range of methods within a Nodes class, all of which will use a struct "listnode" composed of playerName (string) and next (listnode). I have created the struct within a header file as I will be using the struct in the main class also.

**Error:** When I compile, I get an unusual error, its an error "c4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default int" I get this error on like 8.

```
#ifndef STRUCTS_H
#define STRUCTS_H
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

typedef struct 
{
    string playerName;
    listnode * next;
} listnode;

#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are compiling as C++ , you should be able to do:

```
struct listnode
{
   string playername;
   listnode* next;
};
```

(no need for typedef here)

If you want to be able to compile in C, you will need to use a tag-name for the struct:

```
typedef struct listnode_tag
{
   string playername;
   struct listnode_tag* next;
} listnode;
```

(Obviously `string` may need `std::string` to work in C++, and you should have a `#include <string>` in this file, just to make sure it's "complete" on its own).

Answer (score 1):

`string` lives in the `std` namespace, so refer to it as `std::string`. You also don't need the `typedef` syntax in C++:

```
#include <string>

struct listnode
{
    std::string playerName;
    listnode * next;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it:

```
typedef struct listnode
{              ^^^^^^^^  
    std::string playerName;
    ^^^^^
    struct listnode * next;
    ^^^^^^
} listnode;
```

Comment: No real need for `typedef` if it's C++.

Comment: True - I wasn't sure if OP was going for a C/C++-compatible header but I guess not since he's using `<string>`.